# Creating Link to Specific Page through Table field

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm pretty new to HTML, PHP, JavaScript, etc.

I have a table that will be uploaded by a Database, with fields such as name, id,email etc.

I would like to show a page with all people in the table, with a link to a details page that will show all the attributes (field in the table) of the person.

---

I use MySQL and I'm trying to build an Admin interface for better user management.

Comment: Show us some code effort. Then we will assist for that.

Comment: Cleaning up the language.

Comment: I'm still trying to produce some code. At the moment I only have the HTML table ready to receive the information from the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link could be like this `person.php?id=1243`

Where person.php is the page where you display the information about the Person with `id = 1243`

You can retrieve the id by using `$id = $_GET['id']` and then use it on a mysql query:

```
SELECT * from Person WHERE id = $id; // Don't forget to handle SQL injection
```

And you're done.

EDIT: For multiple fields

The link `person.php?id1=1243&id2=5678`

Retrieve the value `$id1 = $_GET['id1']` and `$id2 = $_GET['id2']`

MySQL: `SELECT * from Person WHERE id IN($id1, $id2);`

EDIT2 : For a range of users

The link `person.php?startId=1&endId=5000`

Retrieve the value `$startId = $_GET['startId']` and `$endId = $_GET['endId']`

MySQL: `SELECT * from Person WHERE id BETWEEN $startID AND $endId;`

**ALTERNATIVE suggested by @PierreGranger**

Your link could be like this `person.php?id[]=1243&id[]=5678`

Where person.php is the page where you display the information about the Person with `id = 1243` and `id = 5678`

You can retrieve the id by using `$id = $_GET['id'][0]` and then use it on a mysql query:

```
if ( isset($_GET['id']) && is_array($_GET['id']) ) // Check if parameter is set
{
    $ids = $_GET['id'] ;
    foreach ( $ids as $k => $v )
        if ( ! preg_match('#^[0-9]+$#',$v) ) unset($ids[$k]) ; // Remove if parameters are not identifiers

    if ( sizeof($ids) > 0 ) // If there is still at least 1 id, do your job
    {
        $sql = ' SELECT * from Person WHERE id in (".implode('","',$ids).") ' ;
        $rq = mysql_query($sql) or die('SQL error') ;
        while ( $d = mysql_fetch_assoc($rq) )
        {
            // Do your SQL request and build your table
        }
    }
}
```

Wich will result in :

```
SELECT * from Person WHERE id in ("1234","5678") ;
```

And you're done.

Comment: Will this work for multiple fields?!
User1, User2, etc.

Comment: This works really well with a small amount of fields, just tested it, thanks !

Now, is there a way to make this autonomous? Where I can randomly select a user from the table (the id can vary from 1 to 5000+) and get the same results?!

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Yes you can do that easily by making a range, see my second edit. Don't forget to set the question as resolved.

Comment: I edited to make it works with multiple ids : but 5000 can't be set. If you want to display 5000 persons, you should find an other way to select if (`select * from person where service = "seo"`)...

Comment: @PierreGranger i included your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Akram response you can try this one.
There is 2 cases : if you only have 4 or 5 particular ids, you can do this :
`page.php?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=9`

And if you want to reach a range (id from 1 to 1000) :
`page.php?from=1&to=1000`

```
unset($sql) ;
if ( isset($_GET['id']) && is_array($_GET['id']) ) // Check if parameter is set
{
    $ids = $_GET['id'] ;
    foreach ( $ids as $k => $v )
        if ( ! preg_match('#^[0-9]+$#',$v) ) unset($ids[$k]) ; // Remove if parameters are not identifiers

    if ( sizeof($ids) > 0 ) // If there is still at least 1 id, do your job
    {
        $sql = ' SELECT * from Person WHERE id in ("'.implode('","',$ids).'") ' ;
    }
}
elseif ( isset($_GET['from']) && isset($_GET['to']) )
{
    if ( preg_match('#^[0-9]+$#',$_GET['from']) && preg_match('#^[0-9]+$#',$_GET['to']) )
    {
        $sql = ' SELECT * from Person WHERE id between "'.$_GET['from'].'" and "'.$_GET['to'].'"' ;
    }
}

if ( isset($sql) )
{
    $rq = mysql_query($sql) or die('SQL error') ;
    while ( $d = mysql_fetch_assoc($rq) )
    {
        // Do your SQL request and build your table
    }
}
```